# how to create android app to take backup of the phone

Tags: android, android-contacts

How To create backup of phone data and in case of lost should  retrieve data on another phone from server side database,i want to develop android

Comment: What data would you like to backup? A lot of data is already saved for you in the associated google account of the android device (the first google account you add on the device). When setting that account on the other phone it will restore that data to that phone.

Comment: Titanium backup is an app that does this for you by the way. Can save the data to Dropbox, Google Drive or Box.

Comment: Hi Pulsar thanks for your reply,actually i want to develop an application which stores the contacts information like phone numbers and persons name,if phone was lost, i need to get my contacts information(the data earlier i saved on mobile which was lost) like phone numbers on other phone,this,is my actual requirement

Comment: Added an answer according to your updated information.

Answer (score 0):

With the updated information (contacts backup) I would advise the following:

- Connect the android phone with a google account, all contacts will be saved with the google account and available on other phones registered with that account. Can have multiple accounts. Available in gmail/google contacts as well. Works with google apps accounts as well as gmail.

and/or

- Connect the android phone with an exchange server, can store the contacts there and will be available on other phones connected as well

The power of the cloud (and android). You already have backup of your contacts.

Contacts from one or more of each of these for example are available (and merged into one contact): skype, twitter, gmail, exchange, endomondo, ...(even facebook is possible with workarounds even though facebook ignores the integration on android themselves these days) and many others. Android is very nice regarding this!

Having said that, there is a contacts api and fairly easy to access using standard android content resolvers etc. Please see
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html